# Spring jdbctemplate batch update fast alternative

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to insert around 5000 values into the MySql table using Spring JDBC template batch update like it is shown here

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/

As I understand it is doing as many inserts as many rows I am giving it in one transaction. But it is still slow.

I've tried forming a query like

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
    "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?)....
```

for as many rows I have. It performed much faster but I had to form the query manually. I wonder are there any alternatives for batch update for such cases?

P.S. I know that one should consider maximum package size, the query's size should not exceed the limit(though the limit can be configured in MySql server) when building such big queries.

Comment: Do you have tried `preparedStatement.addBatch(); preparedStatement.executeBatch();` ?

Comment: Yes, no significant influence

Comment: For batch updates to work, make sure you have a JDBC driver version (and database) that supports it, if it doesn't single queries will be executed instead of a batch. Also make sure you have proper transaction setup and are using transactional tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows

1. Get connection object
2. set connections autocommit property to false. using  `connection.autocommit(false)`
3. Run your insert query statement.
4. execute `connection.commit();`

Comment: Good point! It is slower than forming a big query but turned out to fasten the operation to a decent speed. Thanks!

Comment: With a proper transaction setup this isn't needed as spring tx already does this. If this is working this is mainly an indication that you have something wrong in your setup.

Comment: Looking at the sample that is the first thing the sample has wrong no proper transaction setup. The `insertBatchSql` method should be transactional, which it isn't, looking at the sample it completely lacks transaction setup.

Comment: Any downsides of the above method ?

Comment: It works like a charm! I used to use `addBatch()` and `insertBatch()` and the performance was very poor. The duration has decreased from 1 minute to 1 second!. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Deinum Will this also work in the following scenario? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062510/will-transactional-cause-batch-updates-with-jdbctemplate-if-used-in-a-loop