# How to get Connection Object in SimpleJDBCTemplate

Tags: spring, connection, spring-jdbc

How to get Connection Object in SimpleJdbcTemplate. If I use Jdbc template I can get it like this

```
Connection conn = template.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Comment: SimpleJdbcTemplate deprecated in favor of JdbcTemplate https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6922

Comment: Yes I agree that. But in existing application client is using it. my requirement is I need to connection object and make it commit. any way  or I have to go  with JdbcTemplate for this case ?

Comment: Why od you need the connection to commit? The methods on `JdbcTemplate` and   `SimpleJdbcTemplate` take care of the commits themselves. Also you you obtain a connection like that you are getting a new connection not related to anything else and you also need to manage it yourself!.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleJdbcTemplate` was [deprecated](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6922) in favor of JdbcTemplate

You need to inject [datasource](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/69815-how-to-get-the-datasource-in-java-servlet) to commit connection instead of using `SimpleJdbcTemplate`

> You shouldn't use the SimpleJdbcTemplate in the controller you should create separate layers for that. However simply inject the datasource into your controller.

Comment: It is not handled in Controller , it handled in  Separate Layer only. I just tried the below link as I also have batchupdate related performance issues in my application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962750/spring-jdbctemplate-batch-update-fast-alternative